# Run Jquery function on window events: load, resize, and scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I run a jquery function on window events: load, resize, and scroll?

Here is my code
I'm trying to detect if a div is viewable and then if it is run some ajax code...

---

```
<script>
function topInViewport(element) {
    return $(element).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop() && $(element).offset().top          <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
 }

 </script>

<script>
topInViewport($("#mydivname"))
{
// ajax code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use the following. They all wrap the `window` object into a jQuery object.

[Load:](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    topInViewport($("#mydivname"))
});
```

[Resize:](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   topInViewport($("#mydivname"))
});
```

[Scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    topInViewport($("#mydivname"))
});
```

Or bind to them all using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
    topInViewport($("#mydivname"))
});
```

Comment: @user2152326 Yeah you can, go for it :)

Comment: @user2152326 It's not needed, but it's the `event` object. You don't really need to use it. You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event

Comment: I still need two scripts though right? But I should just add this $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e) to the second script I posted?

Comment: @user2152326 With that `on`, you can only have one.

Comment: Won't $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
    topInViewport($("#mydivname"))
}); call the method topInViewport() twice on page load?

Comment: On mac in both Safari and Firefox it is called twice. But on Pc it is only called once. This twice call is a platform issue.

Comment: Or even simpler: `$(window).on("load resize scroll", function_name_here);`

Comment: can you add a namespace to this?

Comment: If there is already a Function/Code attached to that Event, will this  allow that other code to run in addition to the function above?

Answer (score 23):

You can bind listeners to one common functions -

```
$(window).bind("load resize scroll",function(e){
  // do stuff
});
```

Or another way -

```
$(window).bind({
     load:function(){

     },
     resize:function(){

     },
     scroll:function(){

    }
});
```

Alternatively, instead of using `.bind()` you can use `.on()` as bind directly maps to `on()`.
And maybe `.bind()` won't be there in future jquery versions.

```
$(window).on({
     load:function(){

     },
     resize:function(){

     },
     scroll:function(){

    }
});
```

Comment: To my understanding is this not the better answer?

Comment: @AaronMatthews Just different practice of writing code.

Answer (score 4):

just call your function inside the events.

load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  // or  $(window).load(function(){
    topInViewport($(mydivname));
});
```

resize:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    topInViewport($(mydivname));
});
```

scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    topInViewport($(mydivname));
});
```

or bind all event in one function

```
$(window).on("load scroll resize",function(e){
```