# Using the width() method and returning the value as a percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm wanting to use the `width()` method to return the width of an element on my site, by default it will display this in pixels.

I was reading on **[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_width.asp)** that you can change the value to a number of different units such as px, em, pt, etc.

I would like to return the width as a percentage, how can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

**Jquery**

```
$('.range-control').each(function(){
    var container = $(this),
        input = container.find('input'),
        output = container.find('output'),
        rangeWidth = input.width(),
        thumbWidth = container.attr('data-thumbwidth'),
        startValue = input.val(),
        startOffset = ((rangeWidth - thumbWidth) / 100) * startValue;

    output
        .css({
            'left' : startOffset
        });

    $(input).on('input', function(){
        var value = this.value,
            offset = ((rangeWidth - thumbWidth) / 100) * value;

        output
            .val(value)
            .css({
                'left' : offset
            });
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: A percentage of what? The page's width? The parent element's width?

Comment: The parent element's width, the reason I'm needing it as a percentage is because I need it to be responsive.

Answer (score 2):

can't use just calculate it?

```
var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
var thisWidth = $(this).width(); 
var percentWidth = (thisWidth/parentWidth)*100+"%";
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: he means, that it could be easy for you to calculate the value. Doing the following: get the parent width, get the element width and apply the percentage calculation (elemwidth/parentWidht) *100 = percentage.

Eg. (50/100) * 100 = 50; and 50+'%' = 50%;

Comment: Could you perhaps show me how I would include this with my existing code? I'm still learning Jquery.

Comment: create a jsfiddle and i will take a look, not sure there is any reason you need to find %.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL/ as you can see when you resize the brower, the output doesn't align correctly, I thought the this was maybe because the output was being positioned in pixels rather than a percentage. How can I make the output always display inline with the slider thumb, even when the viewport is being resized?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL/1/ you don't need % width, all you need is a `.on('resize', fucntion() {})`  to cal again doing window resize.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there not a better way of doing this? Instead of having to duplicate the code over again?  It seems like a lot of extra code for something so simple.

Comment: Haha, I'm still learning Jquery so forgive me I ask if you go show me what you mean? :)

Comment: `$(window).on('resize load', function() {  // everything goes here });`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665231/run-jquery-function-on-window-events-load-resize-and-scroll

Comment: I'm still confused haha, could you perhaps update the fiddle? Or your answer so I can accept it as working?

Comment: jsfiddle won't work with $(window).on('load'); I believe b/c it use iframe instead of window... http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL/10/

Comment: I tried it locally, it work like it should just copy the code over it should be ok

Comment: Yeah it's working fine locally, and oh yeah JSFiddle does use iframes. Thanks for the help man I really appreciate it, how long have you been coding jQuery?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79876/discussion-between-wlin-and-jordan).