# add/remove class depending on element height on the fly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an element that needs to change height depending on the height of its child p tag:

```
<div id="eventpg" class="bg-pink linkbox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</p>
</div>
```

I've achived the desired change by adding a class if the paragraph is over a certain height:

```
var divheight = $("#eventpg p").height();
if ( divheight > 173) {
    $("#eventpg").addClass("height535");
}
```

Which adds this class this class:

```
. height535{height:535px;}
```

This works fine in most instances but if the user rotates their device from portrait to landscape the added class still remains and the page has to be reloaded to remove it.

How do I achieve the height change 'on the fly' as it were? So if the browser window changes causing the paragraph to change height the container changes to reflect this?

Thanks

Comment: Wrap your statement in a function, then fire that function on window.resize.

Comment: You’ll need a handler function for the relevant events (resize and orientationchange), and in there perform your check again. (Whether using fixed heights is a good solution at all, depends. For example if the user changes the font-size, this might easily break.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the function on `load` and `resize`:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
   var divheight = $("#eventpg p").height();
   if ( divheight > 173) {
       $("#eventpg").addClass("height535");
   }
})'
```

Comment: Load event doesn't fired in `.on()`

Comment: It does. Its just binding events together:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665231/run-jquery-function-on-window-events-load-resize-and-scroll

Comment: That seems to be a jsfiddle issue. See codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrqqvm

Comment: Thanks for your help Derek Story.

Comment: @Mohammad The reason it didn't work for you is because jsfiddle automatically wraps everything in an onload event. You can tell it not to wrap in the javascript options. Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/f28v37cy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for a resize event, adding or removing the class as necessary:

```
var heightThreshold = 173; // controlling the height globally may be easier

$(window).resize(function () {

    var el        = $("#eventpg"),
        divheight = el.find("p").height();

    if ( divheight > heightThreshold ) {
        el.addClass("height535");
    } else {
        el.removeClass("height535");
    }

});
```

or do something similar with e.g. jQuery Mobile's `orientationchange` event - see [here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)

Comment: Thanks for your help The One and Only ChemistryBlob.

Comment: No prob...glad I could help out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. using a combo of The One and Only ChemistryBlob's and Derek Story's answers, the follwoing has worked successfully:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var divheight = $("#eventpg p").height();
    if ( divheight > 173) {
        $("#eventpg").addClass("height535");
    } else {
        $("#eventpg").removeClass("height535");
    }
});
```