# How to combine load & resize with $(window).one("scroll", into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that needs to fire on load, resize and the first time scrolling. How can I combine the following two functions in one, to do that?

Alternative ways are welcome too of course.

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){

});

$(window).one("scroll", function() {

});
```

Comment: Give the function a name, then pass it to each: `function someName() { … } $(window).on('load resize', someName).one('scroll', someName);`

Comment: How about this one [Run Jquery function on window events: load, resize, and scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665231/run-jquery-function-on-window-events-load-resize-and-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using anonymous functions, just create a function declaration and call it from both events:

```
$(window).on("load resize", go);

$(window).one("scroll", go);

function go(e){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var fn = function() {}` do store you fn reference and use in both cases:

```
$(window).on("load resize", fn);

$(window).one("scroll", fn);
```